# Excel lookup inbetween values

Tags: excel, range, vlookup, lookup

I have a question where i have to assign a text rating (remedial-advanced) based on a students score. Example a students score is 8, according to the table they would fall in between the remedial range which is 1-9. How would create a formula in excel to return the value "remedial" in a new column.

[image: Picture of table range]

Comment: Use a lookup table and VLOOKUP with approximate match.

Comment: You can use several vlookups in one formula and implement interpolation. A good exercise :)

Comment: `=INDEX({"remedial","below proficient","proficient","advanced"},MATCH(A1,{1,10,12,14}))` where `A1` refers to the students score.